# Gson seralize a runnable?

Tags: java, gson

Does anyone know how to seralize a Runnable object using Gson's Instance Creator?

Thanks,
Kevin

Comment: The Instance Creator feature is for deserialization, not serialization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned, the Instance Creator feature is for deserialization, not serialization.  Also, use of an Instance Creator to deserialize a `Runnable` is not necessary.

Following is an example of using Gson to serialize and deserialize a `Runnable` instance.

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class GsonFoo
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    BarRun runRunRun = new BarRun();
    runRunRun.name = "Whiskey";
    runRunRun.state = 42;

    String json = new Gson().toJson(runRunRun);
    System.out.println(json);
    // output: {"name":"Whiskey","state":42}

    BarRun runCopy = new Gson().fromJson(json, BarRun.class);
    System.out.println(runCopy.name); // Whiskey
    System.out.println(runCopy.state); // 42
  }
}


class BarRun implements Runnable
{
  String name;
  int state;

  @Override
  public void run()
  {
    // do something useful
  }
}
```

If something about what you're trying to achieve necessitates use of an Instance Creator, then note that examples are available in [the Gson User Guide section on the subject](http://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Writing-an-Instance-Creator), as well as in [the InstanceCreator JavaDocs](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/InstanceCreator.html).

Comment: Thanks a TON Programmer Bruce!

Comment: This is rather an old post, but I was wondering if it is also possible to serialize the content of the ´run()´ function ? I got a ´CustomRunnable´ class which only implements ´Runnable´ and ´Serializable´, but I am not able to retrieve my ´CustomRunnable´ from the serialized object and invoke the ´run()´ function